# Does bool take less storage than uint8 (or the rest of integer types)?

Tags: solidity

I want to keep track of a mapping of addresses with only 2 possible states. Does `uint8` take more storage and consume more gas in my case?

```
contract MyContract {
    mapping(address => bool) boolBackedStatus;
    mapping(address => uint8) uint8BackedStatus;

    function setTrue(address user) {
        boolBackedStatus[user] = true;
        uint8BackedStatus[user] = 1;
    }

    function setFalse(address user) {
        boolBackedStatus[user] = false;
        uint8BackedStatus[user] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood as of `pragma solidity 0.4.19`  both are stored as `uint256`.

The following two contracts use the same amount of gas when calling `add`.

#### As uint8:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract AsUint8 {
    mapping(address => uint8) uint8s;

    function add()
    public
    {
        uint8s[msg.sender] = 1;
    }
}
```

#### As bool:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract AsBool {
    mapping(address => bool) bools;

    function add()
    public
    {
        bools[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```

With an execution cost of 20484. According to quick tests on https://remix.ethereum.org

Comment: Can we conclude that storing `uint8`, `bool` and `uint256` consumes same amount of memory? @Victory

Comment: @Alper thats my understanding. But the compiler's output could change in the future.